# Epimorphism of sheaves is locally surjective on sections

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\phi:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$ be a morphism of sheaves of $R$-modules over a topological space $X$.

I'm aware of the fact that $\phi$ is an epimorphism $\Leftrightarrow \phi_x$ is surjective forall $x\in X$.

I'm trying to prove/disprove the following:

> $\phi$ is an epimorphism $\Leftrightarrow $ every $x\in X$ has an open neighbourhood $U\subset X$ such that $\phi_U:\mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{G}(U)$ is surjective.

The converse $(\Leftarrow)$ is easy, since if $\phi_U$ is surjective, clearly $\phi_x$ is surjective and by arbitrariness of $x$, $\phi$ is an epimorphism.

For $(\Rightarrow)$, I don't know if it's possible to find such $U$.

Any suggestions? Is this just false?

Comment: I don't see how $\phi_U$ being surjective would necessarily imply $\phi_x$ is surjective for $x \in U$ -- what about stalks not defined over all of $U$?

Comment: Something similar is true: for any epimorphism of sheaves $\varphi:\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{G}$, any open subset $U\subset X$, and any section $s\in\mathcal{G}(U)$, there is an open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $U$ and sections $t_i\in \mathcal{F}(U_i)$ so that $\varphi(t_i)=s|_{U_i}$. (This is the content of Hartshorne exercise II.1.3(a), for instance.) The problem comes from trying to go from one section to all sections over some open.